# Android fine volume control

Tags: android, audio, volume

I want to fine tune the volume of the current media file playing.

So there are two applications here, the mediaplayer application, that could be the default Music application, and my application, where I want to tune the volume.

What I do now is to use setStreamVolume, but the index only goes from the max volume to 0, and that's 15 levels only (at least in the emulator).

What I want is to fine tune it in for example, 100 or 200 levels.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just searched around for a bit and it seems like this isn't possible using the android API.

Comment: Actually, if you are playing music and you have an income voice, the system turn down the volume smoothly and then restores it perfectly. It must be possible to do, but perhaps with NDK? Absolutely no idea about how to do it through NDK because I'm not playing any file, is the system volume that I want to tune it...

Comment: @zegnus I have no doubt in my mind that it's possible :) And, the NDK seems like a good place to start. It seems to be poorly documented though...Good luck!

Comment: Yup, I'll post any news about my search.

Answer (score -1):

I think Fine Volume Control is what you want. It provides 100 levels of adjustment. You can get it in market

Comment: Welcome to SO!.  @zegnus is asking about how to do it programmatically.